# Timing of scope-based lock guards and return values

Tags: c++, scope, rvo

```
class C {
    mutable std::mutex _lock;
    map<string,string> deep_member;
public:
    auto get_big_lump()
     {
     std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(_lock); // establish scope guard
     return deep_member;  // copy the stuff while it can't be changed on another thread.
     }
};
```

What is the guaranteed timing with respect to the guard and the copying of the return value?  **Will the copy take place while the lock is held**, or can some of it be done after the function body returns, in the case of allowed (or actual!) optimizations?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All destructor of local objects are called after the function body terminates. Return statement is a part of a function body, so it is guaranteed the lock will be held while the copy is performed.

Optimizations will not change this fact, they will only change the destination for the copy - it could either be an intermediate temporary or the real destination on the call site. The lock will only exist for the first copy, no matter where it is being sent to.

However, please keep in mind the the actual scope lock in the code is not correct. You need `lock_guard` - but it is possible it is simply a demo copy-paste error and real code has real guard in place.

Answer (score 4):

`std::lock` does **not** establish a scope guard! It only locks. It does not unlock. You want this:

```
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(_lock);
```

which locks on construction and unlocks on destruction (which occurs on scope exit).

The initialization of the return value will occur before local variables are destroyed, and hence while the lock is held. Compiler optimizations are not allowed to break correctly synchronized code.

However, note that if the return value is then copied or moved into some other variable, this second copy or move will occur *after* the lock is released.

Comment: Sorry, that's a mistake in the post.

Comment: @Brian Thanks for answering, I also needed to know this. Do you know offhand which clauses in the standard would be infringed upon if a compiler were to not implement this behaviour?

Comment: @sircolinton Which behaviour exactly are you talking about? Please post a new, detailed question.

Comment: @Brian The behaviour described in your answer. I was asking if you're able to provide references to the standard to back up your answer.