# Sequencing between the destruction of local automatic function variables vs the construction of the return value

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, language-lawyer, c++17

There exists code that relies on the fact that local automatic function variables are destroyed after the return value has been created, for example:

1) [Unmangling the result of std::type_info::name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4541470/8414561)

```
std::string demangle(const char* name)
{
    int status = -4;
    std::unique_ptr<char, void(*)(void*)> res {
        abi::__cxa_demangle(name, NULL, NULL, &status),
        std::free
    };
    return (status==0) ? res.get() : name;
}
```

2) [Timing of scope-based lock guards and return values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34731298/8414561)

```
class C {
    mutable std::mutex _lock;
    map<string,string> deep_member;
public:
    auto get_big_lump()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(_lock);
        return deep_member;
    }
};
```

Where does the standard specify this order is guaranteed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[[stmt.return]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.return#3):

> The copy-initialization of the result of the call is sequenced before
>   the destruction of temporaries at the end of the full-expression
>   established by the operand of the return statement, which, in turn, is
>   sequenced before the destruction of local variables ([stmt.jump]) of
>   the block enclosing the return statement.

Answer (score 2):

You tagged multiple language revisions. So I'll note that the quote @songyuanyao brings was not always there. It was amended under [DR 1885](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1885), which details how the return statement was under-specified. Specifically the sequencing related wording was missing in C++14, and that was amended in C++17 under the DR.

Practically, your code is likely correct in C++14 too. Vendors have a high QoI standard.